# Is there any gem to read exif data from png images

Tags: iphone, ruby, exif

I am uploading png images from iphone. I would like to read the gps information from the image. I am using EXIF Reader(GitHub) but it works only for gif and tiff format.

Any solution to read Exif data from png images will be useful

Answer (score 3):

[exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) supports PNG, and there are rubygems wrapping it:

- [multi_exiftool](http://rubygems.org/gems/multi_exiftool)
- [mini_exiftool](http://rubygems.org/gems/mini_exiftool)

I'm not sure what the difference between these two are, though.

Answer (score 1):

[ChunkyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png) supports this

```
img = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file('image.png')
p img.metadata
```